# CSS div not positioning properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a event section in my website. when I put several events in it div position is not proper.
HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-5 round-body" id="events">
            <h1>Events</h1>
              <div class="event-list">
                <div class="event-date">
                  <div class="event-month">May</div>
                  <div class="event-day">06</div>
                </div>
                <div class="event-text">
                  <p><strong>Blah blah blah Work</strong></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="event-list">
                <div class="event-date">
                  <div class="event-month">May</div>
                  <div class="event-day">10-23</div>
                </div>
                <div class="event-text">
                  <p><strong>Blah blah blah</strong></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="event-list">
                <div class="event-date">
                  <div class="event-month">May</div>
                  <div class="event-day">06</div>
                </div>
                <div class="event-text">
                  <p><strong>Blah blah blah Work</strong></p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
.event-list .event-date{
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  background-color: #109902;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 80px;
}
.event-list, .event-month, .event-day{
  width: 100%;
}
.event-date{
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

jsfiddle link is given below
https://jsfiddle.net/u1pucb15/5/

Comment: How do you want them to be positionned exactly ? One below each other, like a menu?

Comment: How it is not proper? What is your expected output?

Comment: exactly. one box under another one. all box will be started from left side

Comment: Simply add a space between your `div` that contains text and the next `div` that contains the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use `display: inline-block` for event-date div

```css
.event-list .event-date{
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        background-color: #109902;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 15px;
        width: 80px;
    }
    .event-list, .event-month, .event-day{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .event-list{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .event-date{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .event-text {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5 round-body" id="events">
    <h1>Events</h1>
    <div class="event-list">
        <div class="event-date">
            <div class="event-month">May</div>
            <div class="event-day">06</div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-text">
            <p><strong>Blah blah blah Work</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-list">
        <div class="event-date">
            <div class="event-month">May</div>
            <div class="event-day">10-23</div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-text">
            <p><strong>Blah blah blah</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-list">
        <div class="event-date">
            <div class="event-month">May</div>
            <div class="event-day">06</div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-text">
            <p><strong>Blah blah blah Work</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `float: left;` to `.event-text`

```
.event-text {
    float: left;
}
```

And `clear: left;` to `.event-list`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1pucb15/8/)**

Comment: @reza Gald to help. Don't forgot to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
.event-list .event-date{
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #109902;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 80px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.event-list, .event-month, .event-day{
    width: 100%;
}
.event-date{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
}


.event-text {
    float: left;
}

.event-list {
    clear: left;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/u1pucb15/10/)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but something closer like this?

```
.event-list .event-date{
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #109902;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 80px;
}
.event-list{
  display:inline-block;
}
.event-month, .event-day{
    width: 100%;
}


.event-date{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```